# How to set multiple launch.json or different arguments in same project folder at Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I usually run python code at Visual Studio Code. And sometimes I open a folder which contains several applications. For example, I use examples repository like https://github.com/pytorch/examples

If I open `pytorch/examples` folder, it contains many `main.py` and they need different arguments for each. In such a case, is there any ways to prepare multiple `launch.json`? `configurations` in `launch.json` is `array`, so it may be a solution in my case..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you had begun to realize, VS Code allows for multiple launch configurations.

You can create one (or another) configuration by going to the debug menu on the left side of the window, clicking the dropdown for selecting which launch configuration to use, and clicking `Add Configuration`.

[image: Adding another launcher]

When you want to switch configurations, just select the one you want to use from the same dropdown menu.

Comment: Nice! I can switch configurations even I run same code, with different arguments!

Comment: El magnifeco! Danken