# launch.json - different arguments for different programs by default?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to edit and test python. I typically open the entire folder in Code and I have multiple python files in the folder. When I have a particular Python file open in the editor and I hit F5 to start debugging, I would like default arguments passed to the program I am debugging vary depending on which file I am debugging. E.g. one set of arguments for p1.py and a different set of arguments for p2.py, but without having to switch debugging configurations. Is that possible?
It seems related to [How to set multiple launch.json or different arguments in same project folder at Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353737/how-to-set-multiple-launch-json-or-different-arguments-in-same-project-folder-at) but not quite what I am looking for. I also looked at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations and if I am reading it right, I am out of luck. (I could create two configurations, one for p1.py and another for p2.py, but I would have to manually switch between those configurations when I switch between those files in the editor.)

Answer (score 2):

With extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) you can select arguments based on the file path.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "args" : ["${input:arg1}","${input:arg2}"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "arg1",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        "/p1.py": "foobar",
        "/p2.py": "blabla"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "arg1",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        "/p1.py": "tralala",
        "/p2.py": ""
      }
    }
  ]
```